# What's the alternative for __match_any_sync on compute capability 6?

Tags: cuda, gpu-warp

In the cuda examples, [e.g. here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/), <del>`__match_all_sync`</del> `__match_any_sync` is used.

Here is an example where a warp is split into multiple (one or more) groups that each keep track of their own atomic counter.

```
// increment the value at ptr by 1 and return the old value
__device__ int atomicAggInc(int* ptr) {
    int pred;
    //const auto mask = __match_all_sync(__activemask(), ptr, &pred); //error, should be any_sync, not all_sync
    const auto mask = __match_any_sync(__activemask(), ptr, &pred);
    const auto leader = __ffs(mask) - 1;  // select a leader
    int res;
    const auto lane_id = ThreadId() % warpSize;
    if (lane_id == leader) {                 // leader does the update
        res = atomicAdd(ptr, __popc(mask));
    }
    res = __shfl_sync(mask, res, leader);    // get leader’s old value
    return res + __popc(mask & ((1 << lane_id) - 1)); //compute old value
}
```

The `__match_any_sync` here splits up the threads in the warp into groups that have the same `ptr` value, so that each group can update its own ptr atomically without getting in the way of other threads.

*I know the nvcc compiler (since cuda 9) does this sort of optimization under the hood automatically, but this is just about the mechanics of `__match_any_sync`*

**Is there a way to do this pre compute capability 7?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** The blog article has now been modified to reflect `__match_any_sync()` rather than `__match_all_sync()`, so any commentary to that effect below should be disregarded.  The answer below is edited to reflect this.

Based on your statement:

> this is just about the mechanics of `__match_any_sync`

we will focus on a replacement for `__match_any_sync` itself, not any other form of rewriting the `atomicAggInc` function.  Therefore, we must provide a mask that has the same value as would be returned by `__match_any_sync()` on cc7.0 or higher architectures.

I believe this will require a loop, which broadcasts the `ptr` value, in the worst case one iteration for each thread in the warp (since each thread could have a unique `ptr` value) and testing which threads have the same value.  There are various ways we could "optimize" this loop for this function, so as to possibly reduce the trip count from 32 to some lesser value, based on the actual `ptr` values in each thread, but such optimization in my view introduces considerable complexity, which makes the worst-case processing time longer (as is typical of early-exit optimizations).  So I will demonstrate a fairly simple method without this optimization.

The other consideration is what to do in the case of the warp not being converged?  For that, we can employ `__activemask()` to identify that case.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1646.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// increment the value at ptr by 1 and return the old value
__device__ int atomicAggInc(int* ptr) {
    int mask;
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 700
    mask = __match_any_sync(__activemask(), (unsigned long long)ptr);
#else
    unsigned tmask = __activemask();
    for (int i = 0; i < warpSize; i++){
#ifdef USE_OPT
      if ((1U<<i) & tmask){
#endif
        unsigned long long tptr = __shfl_sync(tmask, (unsigned long long)ptr, i);
        unsigned my_mask = __ballot_sync(tmask, (tptr == (unsigned long long)ptr));
        if (i == (threadIdx.x & (warpSize-1))) mask = my_mask;}
#ifdef USE_OPT
      }
#endif
#endif
    int leader = __ffs(mask) - 1;  // select a leader
    int res;
    unsigned lane_id = threadIdx.x % warpSize;
    if (lane_id == leader) {                 // leader does the update
        res = atomicAdd(ptr, __popc(mask));
    }
    res = __shfl_sync(mask, res, leader);    // get leader’s old value
    return res + __popc(mask & ((1 << lane_id) - 1)); //compute old value
}



__global__ void k(int *d){

  int *ptr = d + threadIdx.x/4;
  if ((threadIdx.x >= 16) && (threadIdx.x < 32))
    atomicAggInc(ptr);
}

const int ds = 32;
int main(){

  int *d_d, *h_d;
  h_d = new int[ds];
  cudaMalloc(&d_d, ds*sizeof(d_d[0]));
  cudaMemset(d_d, 0, ds*sizeof(d_d[0]));
  k<<<1,ds>>>(d_d);
  cudaMemcpy(h_d, d_d, ds*sizeof(d_d[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++)
    std::cout << h_d[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1646 t1646.cu -DUSE_OPT
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1646
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

(CentOS 7, CUDA 10.1.243, with device 0 being Tesla V100, device 1 being a cc3.5 device).

I've added an optional optimization for the case where the warp is diverged (i.e. `tmask` is not `0xFFFFFFFF`).  This can be selected by defining `USE_OPT`.